# Crystal Reports: Show in same line

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem in Crystal Reports in VB.Net 2010. When I'm inserting two different data there is a white space. I've already searched for possible solutions. Can anyone help me? Here is my example:

[image]

This is just an example output of report. I want to put "CSL" on the same line where "PERA" is every time I generate this report.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  It often helps if you post what you have attempted so others can point out a solution.  Also, you can display your table image right on your post rather than the link.

Comment: I actually don't know anything about crystal reports. I'm just trying to help you post a better question so that people who are familiar can help you. It often helps if you post a **short** snippet of the code you are running that gives you the current behavior.

Comment: This is report preview. Please post Report Design too.
I suppose PERA and CSL are different details, is it true?

Comment: Post your design part so that we can help

Comment: I think you need to use multi-columns option in your details ;).